# Enable SharePoint to an existing project

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to enable SharePoint in Visual Studio 2013 in an existing LightSwitch-SilverLight (DesktopClient, HTMLClient and Server) project. But I can't find the option.

I created a new project HTML LightSwitch and the option of enaling SharePont is avaible in the project menu. But if I add a Client to the project the option of enabling SharePoint dissapeard.
In the properties of the project the tab SharePoint is not either.

So, how can I enable SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713586.aspx, it states "LightSwitch apps for SharePoint can have only a single client project, either HTML Client or Desktop Client."